# What is the correct Git path on 64 bit Windows?

Tags: windows, git, github, jenkins

I am trying to configure Jenkins with GitHub. But Jenkins is not able to find git.exe (Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Git Installations )
and i guess that's because PATH ( Environment Variable) is not set on the Windows server I'm using.

It's a Windows 2012 R2 server with a 64-bit OS. But still when I installed Git, it got installed into **Program Files** instead of **Program Files (86)** and I noticed git.exe is in 3 different locations

C:\Program Files\Git\bin
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core

When I looked into registry **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\GitForWindows**
the value of **LibexecPath** key is set to **C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core**

So which path should I be using on a 64-bit machine?

Answer (score 0):

Use **C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe**